# Can someone pinpoint where I am wrong?

Tags: c++, average

I am trying to make a calculator for my grades average, and I cant seem to find where I am wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string subject[17] = {"Biology", "French"}; //"Sport", "Ed.Antreprenoriala", "Geografie", "Mate", "TIC", "Psihologie", "Romana", "Chimie", "Fizica", "Istorie", "Engleza", "Religie", "Info", "Desen", "Muzica"};
    int mark, numberOfMarks;
    float sumaNote = 0;
    double average, averageSum = 0, finalAverage;

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){

        cout << subject[i] << ":" << "\n";
        cout << "How many marks?" << "\n";
        cin >> numberOfMarks;

        for(int j=0; j < numberOfMarks; j++){
            cin >> mark;
            sumaNote += mark;
        }
        average = sumaNote / numberOfMarks;

        averageSum += round(average);
    }

    cout << endl;

    finalAverage = averageSum/2;

    cout << finalAverage;

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

It's supposed to work like this:
1)takes a subject from the string array;
2)asks how many marks I have for that subject;
3)averages the sum of the marks;
4)repeats until out of array elements (subjects)
5)gets the sum of all subject averages, averages those and outputs the answer;

***every non-natural average needs to be rounded either up or down (hence the round() function);

***there are 17 subjects in total but I only used 2 for experimental use;

Example: Biology:
How many marks?
2
8
10    (it should do (8+10)/2)
French:
How many marks?
3
7
9
10    (it should do (7+9+10)/3

Output should be 9+9/2 = 9

But my code doesn't do that and can't figure out why

Comment: ***But my code doesn't do that and can't figure out why*** That is what a debugger is for. Use it to see what your code is actually doing. Debugging usually involves executing your code 1 line at a time looking at your variables at each step. Debugging is not pressing a play looking button and expecting the debugger to tell you something useful.

Comment: Shouldn't you be resetting (to zero) `sumaNote` sometimes? A minute in a debugger should have helped you find this.

Comment: Yes after you calculate the average you don't want to reuse the previous sum for a different subject.

Comment: I don't understand why ppl put the answer in the comments, when it could have been the answer.  Some1 else could use it in the answer, and get the points.

Comment: ***I don't understand why ppl put the answer in the comments*** There is always a question whether the bug is considered too trivial and should be closed as a typo. At least that is why I usually answer first in the comments before posting an actual answer.

Comment: In addition to the answer you've gotten: `sumaNote` should preferably be of integer type and cast to `double` in `average = static_cast<double>(sumaNote) / numberOfMarks;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add `sumaNote = 0;` within the `i` loop.

Answer (score 1):

About the compilation:

1. <conio.h> header is not used anymore and so is getch() at the end of main function.
2. Use modern compilers like CodeBlocks IDE, Repl Online Compiler to avoid using outdated code.

Program:

1. Added `len` variable which automatically calculates the length of the array.
2. Sum is reset to 0 at the end of the loop before going to the next subject.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string subject[] = {"Biology", "French"}; //"Sport", "Ed.Antreprenoriala", "Geografie", "Mate", "TIC", "Psihologie", "Romana", "Chimie", "Fizica", "Istorie", "Engleza", "Religie", "Info", "Desen", "Muzica"};
    int mark, numberOfMarks;
    float sumaNote = 0;
    double average, averageSum = 0, finalAverage;

    // Find length of array 
    int len = sizeof(subject)/sizeof(subject[0]);

    // changed limit to len
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {

        cout << subject[i] << ":" << "\n";
        cout << "How many marks?" << "\n";
        cin >> numberOfMarks;

        for(int j=0; j < numberOfMarks; j++){
            cin >> mark;
            sumaNote += mark;
        }

        average = sumaNote / numberOfMarks;
        averageSum += round(average);

        sumaNote = 0; // important to reset sum
    }

    cout << endl;

    finalAverage = averageSum/len;

    cout << finalAverage;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well i do use codeblocks, and i used getch() because from what i remember it is used to be able to get the .exe file from the .cpp file (i dont know if this made any sense, still getting used to this stuff)